# NSDate giving wrong year

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

We are facing a strange issue using NSDate and NSDateFormatter, when we use below code to get date

```
    NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater1 setDateFormat:@"YYMMddHHmm"];
    NSString *date = [formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"date %@", date);
```

OUTPUT: **16**12301102

We are getting wrong year i.e. 16 instead of 15. Everything is working fine before 26 December. We faced this problem last year too and on 1st jan onwards everything works fine.

Anyone is getting same issue???

Comment: use `YYYY` instead of `yy`

Comment: Try it here solve it..=>   NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater1 setDateFormat:@"YYMMddHHmm"];
    NSString *date = [formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"date %@", date);

Answer (score 0):

Use `yy` instead of `YY` to get correct year